# Fiware MQTT IoT Agent: need to have slashes in the API Key

Tags: mqtt, fiware, api-key

We have are using the Fiware MQTT Iot Agent.  We understand that the topic should be in the format /api_key/device_id/attrs when publishing data from the device.

But we have a requirement where our topic is a long string with multiple slashes in it. But Fiware currently is not supporting any additional slashes(/) in api_key.

Can you please let us know if there is a way to overcome this issue.  Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use a *Standard* IoT Agent for that, you will need to create your own custom IoT Agent.

The definition of the MQTT Topics to subscribe to can be found within [MQTTBinding.js](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/lib/bindings/MQTTBinding.js)

The reading of incoming messages can be found in [commonBindings.js](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/lib/commonBindings.js#L246)

To alter the  path you will need to follow the instructions found in [205 - Custom IoT Agent](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Custom-IoT-Agent)

- clone the [base repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul)
- branch from the **latest** release.
- Amend `MQTTBinding.js` and `commonBindings.js` to listen to your preferred  location
- Create your own [Dockerfile](https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Custom-IoT-Agent/blob/master/iot-agent/Dockerfile) which uses the `COPY` instruction

Obviously same applies if using the JSON IoT Agent.